# How to turn unique observations into variables (columns) in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data.frame with a variable CONTINENT and some other numeric variables per day.  So I have, for instance, 10 rows of "Europe" and then 15 rows of "South America" in this column CONTINENT. I want to create a new data.frame with the following columns: DATE and each continent, but the observations in each continent would correspond to another variable of interest, for instance, temperature. Maybe it's an easy problem, but I don't know how to resolve this. I appreciate if someone can help :)

Comment: In order to help you it is better if you add a sample of your data, like `dput(yourdata)` and paste the output with your question!

Comment: Please provide an example data frame to work with, along with your expected output.  It's much harder to know exactly what you're hoping to do when you've described your question only with words.

Comment: I have like:

DATE <- ("2020-02-25", "2020-03-25", "2020-04-25", "2020-02-25", "2020-03-25", "2020-04-25")
CONTINENT <- ("Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "America", "America", "America")
TEMPERATURE <-(10, 9, 12, 20, 21, 27)

whatever = data.frame(DATE, CONTINENT, TEMPERATURE)

I want europe, america, etc, to become columns. And then the temperature would be in each row by DATE.

Comment: @Jones Please update your post with the data that you have and show expected output for it. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to use is `tidyr::pivot_wider` like such:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from=CONTINENT,
    values_from=TEMPERATURE
  )
```